# Mvc State replacement

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm having hard time understanding the stateless issue with mvc.
Let's say i have a screen with a list of people. i want to choose one of them, and once i selected this person i want to keep his ID, and from my left menu i want to open a screen with his orders, a screen with his account details....
In ASPX i would just keep his PersonID in the session, and use it all over the website.
How can i do the same in mvc? what if i keep his id in a public variable in a public static class? will it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  a session, just as in ASPX.

With a static class with a static `PersonID` property, it will be shared by all users...
Meaning every time you set the value, all users will get the same value : not exactly what you want, do you ?

> So the Web Forms model essentially abstracted a number of features to
>   provide a **simulated stateful model** for Web developers. As a result,
>   you didn't have to be a Web expert with a lot of HTML and JavaScript
>   knowledgeto write effective Web applications.
>
> To simulate stateful programming over the Web, ASP.NET Web Forms
>   introduced features such as viewstate, postbacks, and an overall
>   event-driven paradigm.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942833.aspx

Comment: if i have a session then why everyone say it's stateless?

Comment: I can imagine that it's just because MVC doesn't have a ViewState, which gives a "transparent" way to manage states. In mvc you have to manage your session manually. HTTP is stateless.

Comment: "all users will get the same value...". It's good you told me this, because i was about to...:).

Answer (score 1):

Its not MVC that is stateless, its HTTP. The workaround in ASP.NET and other web technologies are a server side session state and some kind of associating the stateless http requests from one client to one server side session object (this is done with cookies normally).

So just use the `Session` or `TempData` properties.

Comment: Ok. i need to learn more. i feel like i don't know how things work.